# parsing facebook event.description string into website using fql/php/javascript/html

Tags: php, html, facebook-fql

Currently, I'm trying to parse the event.description string information into my website. I've been able to successfully read the event.description data from fql and view this on my website. However, I have to use the "pre" html tag (instead of "p" tag) otherwise the spaces and gaps between text (present on the facebook event site) are missing.

I would like to be able to format the text in this string without losing the 'space/paragraph' information. How can this be done ?

In the end, I would like event information on my website to look very similar to the facebook version of the event.

Comment: Could you please post an example of what you are trying to parse?

Comment: well any facebook event.description data. I've worked out that this must be a problem with how the <p> html tag deals with string literals... it just ignores them whereas <pre> uses them. I need to use the <p> tag (or something similar) where string literals are taken into account.